# Correlation between number of success (X) to total number of trials (N)

Tags: covariance, correlation, binomial-distribution

I have to come up with an expression that provides correlation between number of success( with probability p ) to total number of trials. The distribution of experiments is binomial. According to formula first I have to find covariance and divide by standard deviation of X and N. I am looking for a generalized solution.

Comment: What is the probability distribution of $N$?

Comment: N is total number of trials so it is also binomial

Comment: In the usual setup the number of trials is a constant (which doesn't make much sense in this context). I've never seen something where it's binomial, so I doubt it, (and even if so, what parameters?)

Comment: I suspect that what is meant is that $X_N|N$ is binomial. That is, $X_N=\sum_{i=1}^N B_i$ is a stochastic sum of $N$ independent and identically distributed Bernoulli random variables. Hence, if $N$ is fixed $X_N$ is binomial, but if $N$ is itself a random variable, $X_N$ is dependent on it and they are thus correlated.

Comment: My apologies I misunderstood the distribution of $N$ it is $N$~Poisson(λ). I have to find the correlation between $N$ (the number of trials) and X (the number of success) in form of generalized expression. Thanks.

Comment: That still does not tell us how $X$ and $N$ are related. For all we know, they might be independent and the correlation would be zero.